# Fixing php sizeof warning/error in WordPress plugin file with count()

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm using the Hierarchical Pages plugin on a site and I notice that if I flip to a newer version of PHP, it errors out and it appears that using `sizeof` in this particualr instance is the culprit:

```
if (($args['show_home'] == 'yes') || (sizeof($page_info[$front_page]['children']))) {
      $page_info[$front_page]['show'] = 1;  // always show front page
    }
```

To be honest, I'm not too familiar with this plugin, but after doing some digging it looks like it should be using something like `count((array)...)`. So I updated it to this:

```
    if (($args['show_home'] == 'yes') || (count((array)$page_info[$front_page]['children']))) {
      $page_info[$front_page]['show'] = 1;  // always show front page
    }
```

And that seems to clear out the error, but I just want to make sure if that's a good or correct thing to implement and if I'm missing anything.

Comment: Can you post the specific error message? Also, are you talking about [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/hierarchical-pages/)? If so, the author listed it as [abandoned 4 year ago](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/abandoned-suggestions-for-replacement/)

Answer (score 0):

Modifying a contributed plugin is not suggested. If you ever update that plugin it may reintroduce the error. The best approach is to fork the plugin or submit a patch to the plugin developer.

Other than that `sizeof()` is just an alias of `count()` so if that resolves the error I would just issue roll with it.